# Prove: $∀x ∈ Z, ∃y ∈ Z,(x^2 + y^ 2 + 1)(3x + y) = 0.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I know how to prove specific sentences that start with ∃, and how to prove specific sentences that start with ∀, but I am not sure how to tie them together here. I need to use both of the previous proof templates and work towards a solution from both of them.

I am assuming the format of my proof looks something like this:
Let $x∈Z$.
Now $x$ is an integer.
...
...
Therefore $(x^2 + y^2 + 1)(3x + y) = 0.$

EDIT: Here is my finished proof. Is this correct?

Proof.
Let $x∈Z$. Now $x$ is an integer.
Let $y = -3x$. Now $y$ is an integer.
Then $(x^2 + (-3x)^2 + 1)(3x - 3x) = (x^2 + (-3x^2) + 1)(0) = 0.$
Therefore $(x^2 + y^2 + 1)(3x + y) = 0.$

Comment: If you can let $y$ be an integer depending on $x$ such that $(x^2+y^2+1)(3x+y)=0$, then the proof is over.

Comment: Just a remark on style: saying "now $x$ is an integer" just after writing "$x\in\Bbb Z$" is a bit redundant and looks poorly redacted. Other than that, yes, your proof is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For all $ x \in \mathbf{Z} $, there exists $ y = -3x \in \mathbf{Z} $ such that $ (x^2 + y^2 + 1)(3x + y) = (x^2 + (-3x)^2 + 1)(3x + y) = (10x^2 + 1)(3x - 3x) = 0 $.

Comment: I edited my original question using this solution. Can you confirm the steps I took are correct (specifically the order in which my statements are written for the proof?"

Comment: Your proof is good.